# how to make custom error pages work across all folders htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file, redirect, directory

**Issue:**

I am trying to redirect my error pages to one central location.  For example, I have a folder called "errors" placed in my root directory - however, I have several other folders within this directory, all of which has it's own set of files/folders...If a user views a page via one of these other folders but the page doesn't exist, how can I display my custom error page to them if that error page is in the root directory?

**Sample:**

This is what I have in my root directory's htaccess file.  I have a folder called "errors" that contain the files "400, 401, 403, 404, 500" respectively.

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
```

Now, if I have a second folder within this root folder called "projects" and within this folder I have a htaccess file, how can I make it where on that htaccess file, the error pages to be displayed via my root directory?

**Here is what I've tried:**

```
ErrorDocument 400 /../errors/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /../errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /../errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /../errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /../errors/500.php
```

Where adding the "/../" I would assume it would go into the root directory...However, it's not.  If I take out the first "/", that doesn't work either...

I've searched all over the net trying to figure this out, but to no avail.  Everything just states that, for example, this works:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
```

which it does, but doesn't work if a user is in a different folder viewing a file within.

**To sum this up:**

*example.com/kdkdkdkd.html*

If this file doesn't exit in the root directory, then this works - but

*example.com/projects/kdkdkdkd.html*

this doesn't since the file is within the projects folder - My custom error page doesn't display in this scenario even though I have my htaccess file within the projects folder setup...Any ideas how to get this to work?

=================================================

Update:  The way I have it all setup right now (which does work, but I feel is unneccesary and takes up additional space) is that within each folder I have created a folder called "errors"...and within that folder the custom error pages...This method works, but seems so wasteful.

For example:

root directory

```
• errors (folder)
    - 400.php
    - 401.php
    - 403.php
    - 404.php
    - 500.php
• projects (folder)
    - errors (folder)
        - 400.php
        - 401.php
        - 403.php
        - 404.php
        - 500.php
    - .htaccess
    - index.php
• .htaccess
• index.php
```

As noted, this method works, but seems so wasteful.  How can I direct the htaccess in the projects folder so that the custom error pages are displayed from the root directory error pages rather than the projects error pages?

Comment: So I think I may have found out the reason behind this not working.  It appears that if on the same domain, this works just fine...but if you have a sub-domain, sadly, this doesn't work.  Since it is a sub-domain, it needs its own set of custom error pages - is this correct?